# Laravel - Class Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am watching a series on tutsplus about building a real application with Laravel. The series was created last year. I assume it was for Laravel 3.

There were a lot of changes I assume and I found out most of them so far and replaced it from the old code. But I can not figure this one out.

In the following code, I get the error `ReflectionException - Class questions does not exist` even though the class I know is there. I did try composer update and auto-dumb but same output.

I assume there is something wrong with ether of these files:

Code:

QuestionsController.php

```
class QuestionsController extends BaseController {
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('questions.index')
            ->with('title', 'Make it snappy Q&A - Home');
    }
}
```

Route.php:

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'questions@index'
));
```

Why does it give an error?

Comment: There is no `$restful` property in L4 anymore, to use RESTful controllers you would use `Route::controller('/', 'QuestionsController');` and name your methods `getIndex`, `getSomething`, `postSomethingElse`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that should work

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'QuestionsController@get_index'
));
```